# Using value to get key correspondent to that value in a nested dictionary that has a list for each key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, key-value

I have a nested dictionary that shows the divisions of each MLB sport team with the Division being a key and the values being the teams in that division. Each key would have about 5 values. What I need to do is reverse map it so that I'm able to return the division of a given team.

```py
    Divisions_dict = {

    'ALCentral' : ['Chicago White Sox' , 'Cleveland Indians' , 'Detroit Tigers' , 'Minnesota Twins' , 'Kansas City Royals'] ,

    'ALEast' : ['New York Yankees' , 'Boston Red Sox',  'Tampa Bay Rays' , 'Toronto Blue Jays' , 'Baltimore Orioles'],

    'Comeon' : 'hello'
    }

    def get_key(val):
      for key, value in Divisions_dict.items():
        if val == value:
          return key

      return "key doesn't exist"

    print(get_key('hello'))
    print(get_key('Toronto Blue Jays'))
```

I know I'm doing it wrong & think it has something to do with the fact that the teams are in list form inside the dictionary. [This is the code I have tried but to no avail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iibek.png). When I run the program, it prints the first line but when I ask it to print the key for `"Toronto Blue Jays"` it returns `"key doesn't exist"`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that the teams being in a list is whats messing it up.

```py
def get_key(val):
  for key, value in Divisions_dict.items():
     if val == value or val in value:
        return key

  return "key doesn't exist"
```

The slight modification adding `or val in value` will account for that. Keep in mind that that will also return true if the value you are searching for is a substring of a value that isn't in a list. For instance if you were looking for `'he'` it would find it in `'hello'`. If you really want to make sure that doesn't happen you could test if the value is a string.

```py
def get_key(val):
  for key, value in Divisions_dict.items():
    if isinstance(value, str):
      if val == value:
        return key
    else:
      if val in value:
        return key

  return "key doesn't exist"
```

As an aside I would recommend returning something like `None` instead of `"key doesn't exist"`. Its one of the things `None` is meant for and now you can have `"key doesn't exist"` as a key!

Answer (score 3):

You can build the reverse dict by iterating over the original one and updating with `dict.fromkeys`:

```
teams_dict = {}
for division, teams in Divisions_dict.items():
    teams_dict.update(dict.fromkeys(teams, division))
```

Alternatively you can use a dict comprehension:

```
teams_dict = {team: division
              for division, teams in Divisions_dict.items()
              for team in teams}
```

Comment: comprehension is the most elegant way